# Drupal 7 : get user profile picture at registration

Tags: drupal, registration

I am using Drupal 7.

I follow [this](http://drupal.org/node/22271) link to enable profile picture of user.

Now i want to get profile picture from user at the time of registration.

How can i get this?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideal module to do this is [Reg-With-Pic](http://drupal.org/project/reg_with_pic)
You will be given a check box at admin/config/people/accounts named "Enable user pictures on registration" and weight selection.

If you are using Content Profile module, File field would be an option.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the **Helper function** to add default user account fields to user registration and edit form.

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user.module/function/user_account_form/7

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to use the Gravatar module to take some of the pain out of what you are suggesting. It's enough trouble to set up a profile on yet another site that you might not want to force them to configure their profile at the time of registration, especially with such things as a "user picture", unless you really want to put a damper on registrations.

Depending on the type of site you are working on, the Gravatar module might be ideal. Anyone who already has a Gravatar will have it automatically set as their user picture.

http://drupal.org/project/gravatar